# Executing a separated command using execvp in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, exec

I've separated a given command from the user into substrings , here's the code :

```
     int i;

     char *line = malloc(BUFFER);
     char *origLine = line;
     fgets(line, 128, stdin);   // get a line from stdin


     // get complete diagnostics on the given string

     lineData info = runDiagnostics(line);

     char command[20];
     sscanf(line, "%20s ", command);
     line = strchr(line, ' ');

     printf("The Command is: %s\n", command);

     int currentCount = 0;                  // number of elements in the line
     int *argumentsCount = &currentCount;   // pointer to that


     // get the elements separated

     char** arguments = separateLineGetElements(line,argumentsCount);


     // here we call a method that would execute the commands


    if (execvp(*arguments,*argumentsCount)  < 0)       // execute the command
    {
                printf("ERROR: exec failed\n");
                exit(1);
    }
```

When I execute the command in `execvp(*arguments,*argumentsCount)` , it fails .

What's wrong ?

Thanks .

**EDIT :**

The input from the user is : `ls > a.out`  , hence I have 3 strings , which are :

`ls` , `>` , `a.out`  , and it fails .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From man page of execvp command:

```
   int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

The second argument is a list of null-terminated C-strings as arguments to the command to be executed by `execvp`. But in your code, you pass an `int` as the second argument which is wrong.

If you have list of arguments in the variable `arguments` then call execvp as:

```
execvp(arguments[0],arguments);
```

Comment: This is the reason for failure, but also note Oli's answer below. Even if you fix the parameters to execvp, you're going to execute `ls` with the parameters `>` and `a.out`, which is going to look for a file named `>` and then a file named `a.out`. That probably isn't what you meant.

Comment: I thought Rob answered that part. Your redirection is not working as you create a new process. system command would be more straight-forward with the way you use your command & arguments.

Comment: Also ls > a.out doesn't make much sense. I guess that's not what wante to do.

Comment: With system command, It is simply: system(" ls > myfile"); You can also look at `popen`.

Comment: @KingsIndian: I can't use it ,I need to use `execvp` . I guess I'll to change the code a little bit to make this works.

Answer (score 2):

Shell redirection won't work if you aren't invoking a shell.  <strike>You also won't have path searching to find  the ls program.</strike>  Some options

- use system() instead, and exit when it returns
- exec a shell and have it run your command
- setup redirection as a shell would, then fork and execute each required child program.

Also your command doesn't make a lot of sense, you probably want ¦ instead of  > and may need to specify the directory of a.out if it is not in your path.  Consider giving it a meaningful name as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `ls > a.out` at the command-line, `>` and `a.out` are not arguments passed to the application; they're interpreted by the shell to redirect stdout.

So in short, it is not possible to do what you want to do.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Well, it is, but not this way.  Your application would need to interpret the arguments, create the file, and set up a stream redirect.</sub>

Comment: Well, you can `execvp("/bin/sh",["-c","your shell commands here"])`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Can you give an example for fixing this bug ,something like what you suggested ? thanks .

Comment: @ron: I've answered two of your questions before, and you never accepted any answer...